# uiGrid switch rows and columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

This is a bit of a general question into the possibilities of ui grid. I have had tremendous success with ui grid thus far. Now I have a use case where I want to switch the rows and columns of the grid.

Basically, I would like the headers to be displayed 'vertically' in the first column and to have the rows become columns.

Is this possible with ui grid?

Comment: how about css transition, you can rotate grid!!

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu simply rotating the grid via css will not give me quite what I am looking for. With some brute-forcing I could potentially rotate the grid and style it to look appropriate. Assuming that I did do that, changes in the future could make the styling hard to maintain. On top of that the bigger issue would be whether or not the logic and the modules would still be applicable if the paradigm of the grid was rotated.

Comment: I am curious - did you figure something else out?  I have the same question :-)

Comment: @ryan alberts I ended up rolling my own grid. Not as impressive, but, did what I needed

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know UI-grid doesn't support this. I doubt if you can do that. May be try building ColumnsDef and Data dynamically and pass it to gridOptions. Or else add extra column and this should be the first column where you will pass all the header values. Change the background of the cells to look like header cells. Now add second column where you pass the entire first row values. Hide the original header row completely. see now u got your required grid........ :)