# Make the header vertically with AngularJS and CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

How can I make the header vertically

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 1,
            enableFiltering: true,
            rowHeight: 35,
            data: data,
            columnDefs: [
        {
name: 'Category', field: 'Category', displayName: 'This is a very long header' , enableCellEdit: false  , width :'180'    
}
```

by setting it vertically it will save me a lot of space.

thanks,

Comment: what do you mean by *how can I make the header vertically*? Share what you have tried so far through a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by header you mean menu (navigation bar)
Check this : http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/menu.html#vertical-menu

**Note**: AngularJS have nothing to do with UI.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, do you want to swap rows with columns and vice-versa? If yes the angular ui grid doesnot support this.

Please have a look at possible similar question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816875/uigrid-switch-rows-and-columns).